# Azure - 'Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, excel, azure

I am working with MS Excel files in my web application is hosted on Azure

I never run into following error when I am trying to access the excel file on my development fabric, but once I deploy to Azure, I get this error message.

`The 'Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

I do not want to change my code and cannot use any 3rd party tool. My questions are:

1. Is there a way around this issue?
2. Can I create a VM on Azure, install the OLEDB Driver and upload my site there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Azure remote site The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153308/windows-azure-remote-site-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such support is there. I guess the development fabric is flawed in this area of azure

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything with an Azure VM that you can with a local machine :)

Just create one through the portal, login to it and go here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148820/how-to-install-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-on-win7-64b-with-sqlexpress-2008) you may also need to download SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe from [here](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=1695&ei=F5xfU_iaKYvPkQW0woCQBg&usg=AFQjCNFmtehTTCFb2l9EYNnWqHxMtj6H-Q&sig2=KgZJ1UB9Mol_Kfyro7cqOA&bvm=bv.65397613,d.dGI) and tick `Allow In Process calls` in the provider.

Comment: Sir , I am getting this problem on my Azure Website not on my Azure VM. Can u explain how can I deploy my website on azure via The Azure VM

Comment: @tusharnarang Here's a great post I usually point people to for that: http://www.nimbo.com/blog/how-to-setup-an-azure-virtual-machine-as-a-web-server/